# uninstall Python3 downloaded from command line tools

Tags: python-3.x, uninstallation, arm64, apple-m1, command-line-tool

I installed python 3.8.2 using xcode command line tools but now according to this [article](https://medium.com/codex/installing-tensorflow-on-m1-macs-958767a7a4b3) I should remove it to download Miniforge3. I didn't know how to do it so now I encountered this error when I ran command

```
file $(which python)
```

[architecture error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0ciJ.png)

According to the article and some online sources, it should only show arm64 but mine showed arm64e. When I navigated to condabin folder and try running conda init it crashed.

I think I should remove Python3 and start Miniforge installation process again, but I don't know how to delete it. I tried

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python3
```

but it said: Operation not permitted